# let vs var performance in nodejs and chrome

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, google-chrome

When I test following code in chrome and nodejs, I get following:

**Chrome:**

> for loop with VAR: **24.058ms**
>   for loop with LET: **8.402ms**

**NodeJS:**

> for loop with VAR: **4.329ms** 
>   for loop with LET: **8.727ms**

As per my understanding, because of block scoping LET is faster in chrome. But can someone help me understand why is it opposite in NodeJS? 
Or am i missing something?

```
"use strict";
console.time("for loop with VAR");
for (var i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1) {
 // Do nothing
}
console.timeEnd("for loop with VAR");

console.time("for loop with LET");
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1) {
 // Do nothing
}
console.timeEnd("for loop with LET");`
```

PS: Not sure if this is not the ideal way to test performance.

Comment: When I flipped the order of tests, the first one (let) was faster. In approx the same proportion.

Comment: what version of node are you using?

Comment: @maioman using v5.10

Comment: The problem with tests like that is that it's (at least in principle) possible for the runtime optimization to figure out that the code has no side-effects at all, and simply not do it. Make the loops actually do something (something cheap) and see what difference that makes.

Comment: @Pointy my point is, are we ready to replace `var` with `let` in **nodejs** development.

Comment: Well *my* point is that the difference in overhead may be completely overshadowed by the cost of the actual real work your code is doing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

V8 version shipped with node.js 5.10 [don't support](http://node.green/#let) the [temporal dead zone](http://jsrocks.org/2015/01/temporal-dead-zone-tdz-demystified/) for let bindings.

Chrome instead is using V8 5.0 that support it...but as the vm is not yet optimized to handle TDZ, is normal that for now it's slower (I remember reading people who assert that replacing var with let made the code about 27% slower).

Answer (score 3):

When you do

```
for (let i = 0; i < 1000000; i += 1) { }
```

the i value in each loop cycle is a separate reference, which is useful when using the i value in an asynchronous callback. This is slower, but can be faster than alternatives in this usage case.

When instead you use

```
let j;
for (j = 0; j < 1000000; ++j) { }
```

you will only have one value reference, and it will be just as fast as with var.

Try the following code

```
console.time("let i");
for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; ++i) { }
console.timeEnd("let i");
console.time("let j");
let j;
for (j = 0; j < 10000000; ++j) { }
console.timeEnd("let j");
console.time("var k");
for (var k = 0; k < 10000000; ++k) { }
console.timeEnd("var k");
```

this will give results like

```
let i: 91ms
let j: 25ms
var k: 27ms
```

where clearly let is equally fast to var when used correctly.

Also to see the difference in asynchronous behaviour, try

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
    setImmediate(() => { console.log(i) });
}
let j;
for (j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
    setImmediate(() => { console.log(j) });
}
for (var k = 0; k < 3; ++k) {
    setImmediate(() => { console.log(k) });
}
```

which will output

```
0
1
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
```

as in each cycle of the loop for let i the i value is a unique reference, which is what causes the slight overhead, whereas for the other two loops it's the same reference.

Answer (score -1):

i can't tell you more but as mentiont in this video (very good), you need smarter code to test this. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=65-RbBwZQdU
the compiler will to *magic* stuff with your code and might even ereas the loop if you don't use `i` and the loop is empty

Comment: Could it be that let is behaving normally , but only var seems weird? Since both "let" have similar results.

Comment: i don't know what the compiler does but it could be since let is only created for the `for` scope but var could also be used outside